# Is it a good idea/possible to define a router url in an angular4 app at runtime?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am building an angular app with angular4 and I received a suggestion from an architect to receive a JSON object from a REST api call which amongst other stuff contains the router link path for a component. To me this means that this path must be placed in the RouterConfig object at runtime which already has a component defined. If this solution is implemented then I am tempted to code the RouterConfig object as the following.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:"component-1",
    component: Component1
  },
  {
    path:"",
    component:Component2
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The JSON object would look something like this:

```
{
  ...
    "label":"ComponentName",
    "path":"router/link/path/for/component"
  ...
}
```

The 3 periods indicate other irrelevant stuff that would be included in the object. So basically the object will include the component name as well as the url link.

Please notice Component2. There is no path defined because I will define this at runtime with the path retrieved from the JSON object if this solution is implemented.

I don't really see the point of this, because I must still build component2 which is the majority of the work, and it is not a requirement that our users define the path for components, the developers get to do that anyway so yeah...My question is, is this possible? Is this a good idea?

Comment: Can you include a short sample (like one entry) of how that json with the path looks like? Does it also contain a name for the component it expects, or will that generic path always map to `Component2`?

Comment: @FredrikLundin Thanks yes I edited the comment

Comment: The object will have the name of the component as well as the path

Comment: The path will always map to component2

Comment: I would probably suggest leaving the router with `path: '*'` and map it to a wrapper component. Then let the wrapper component create the component from the path dynamically (get component name from path=. Would that be something? 
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: I guess it's like said above. See https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router for instance.